# Cannot read value from SYS_CONTEXT

Tags: oracle, web-applications, jdbc, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a PL/SQL procedure which sets some variable in user session, like the following:-

```
Dbms_Session.Set_Context(
    NAMESPACE =>'MY_CTX',
    ATTRIBUTE => 'FLAG_NAME',
    Value => 'some value');
```

Just after this (in the same procedure), I try to read the value of this flag, using:-

```
SYS_CONTEXT('MY_CTX', 'FLAG_NAME');
```

The above returns nothing. How did the DB lose this value? The weirder part is that if I invoke this proc directly from Oracle SQL Developer then it works. It doesn't work when I invoke this proc from my web application from callable statement.

**--EDIT--**

Added an example as to how we are invoking the proc from our Java code.

```
String statement = "Begin package_name.proc_name( flag_val => :1); END;";
OracleCallableStatement st = <some object by some framework>
    .createCallableStatement(statement);
st.setString(1, 'flag value');
st.execute();
st.close();
```

Comment: is the query on sys_context in the same tx phase? Does your app server use dedicated or shared server processes?

Comment: I do not know, but the value is set and is being read in the same proc method. The does not seem to get set, but I do not get any SQL exception.

Comment: do you set and read in one and the same call? Do you use the same accounts for both your SQLDeveloper test as for your appserver tests ?

Comment: For both web app and sqldeveloper I am using the same user name and schema. I set and read in the same procedure, so yes it happens in the same call.

Comment: @AppleGrew The context value will retain until you close the jdbc connection. I think since you closes the connection, the context value is null.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimalistic implementation of your scenario:

```
create or replace package my_ctx
as
    procedure set_flag_name (str varchar2);
    function get_flag_name return varchar2;
end my_ctx;
/

create or replace package body my_ctx
as
    procedure set_flag_name (str varchar2)
    is
    begin
        dbms_session.set_context(
            NAMESPACE =>'MY_CTX',
            ATTRIBUTE => 'FLAG_NAME',
            Value => str);
    end set_flag_name;

    function get_flag_name return varchar2
    is
    begin
        return SYS_CONTEXT('MY_CTX', 'FLAG_NAME');
    end get_flag_name;
end my_ctx;
/
```

As you can see, it works:

```
SQL> exec my_ctx.set_flag_name('Jolly Roger')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select my_ctx.get_flag_name from dual
  2  /

GET_FLAG_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jolly Roger

SQL>
```

So, the issue must lie somewhere in your code.  You will need to examine your program looking for the problem.  Alternatively, post an entire sample here.  Please make sure it's *the smallest working test case possible*.  None of us wants to sift through hundreds of lines of shonky source looking for a bug.  We get enough of that with our own code :)

Comment: Sorry I cannot post my code, but can you suggest some scenarios where this might not work and I can carry out the tests to determine which one is applicable to it?